# QGraphicsitem emit signal when selected/unselected?

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsitem

Could any one gives some hint on the easy way to get a signal emitted when the QGraphicsitem is selected/unselected each time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [itemChange()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html#itemChange) to get notified of that (or emit your own signal if you really need it from there):

> QVariant QGraphicsItem::itemChange ( GraphicsItemChange change, const QVariant & value ) [virtual protected]

more or less like (pseudocode)

```
QVariant QGraphicsItemSubclass::itemChange( GraphicsItemChange change, 
                                                 const QVariant &value ) {
    if ( change == QGraphicsItem::ItemSelectedChange ) {
        if (value == true) {
          // Handling selection.. / selection emission
```